# How Can I Repeat Local Notifications for Evey Hours in Every Day?

Tags: ios, swift

I researched at google and I created local notifications for my app (Wash Hands reminder) but I think I made a mistake on it because I set it between 08:00 Am - 10:00 PM every day but it sent first notification at 9:00 AM but it`s not repeated at 10:00.

UI screenshot will help you understand what I want to do.

[image]

Function:

```
 func createNotify(){
    let now = Date().shortTime
    if now < endTime.shortTime{

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = titles.randomElement()!
        content.body = contents.randomElement()!
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

        let interval:TimeInterval = 3600.0 // 1 minute = 60 seconds
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:"washHands", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    }else{
        print("do nothing")
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            if settings.authorizationStatus != .authorized {
                self.center.requestAuthorization(options: self.options) { (accepted, error) in
                    if !accepted {
                        print("Error")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        center.delegate = self

        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(
            forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.labters.korona-evdekal.washHands",
            using: DispatchQueue.global()
        ) { task in
            self.scheduleLocalNotification()
        }

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        return true
    }


func scheduleLocalNotification() {
        let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "com.labters.korona-evdekal.washHands")
        request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = false
        request.requiresExternalPower = false
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600.0)
        do {
        try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
            HealthView().createNotify()
        } catch {
        print("Could not schedule notification: (error)")
        }
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        willPresent notification: UNNotification,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions)
        -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger) instead?

Comment: It will fire once per day, you have to create 24 notifications and set them all to repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let interval:TimeInterval = 60.0 // 1 minute = 60 seconds

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: true)
```

Use `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` instead of `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`  because `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` object is used when you want to schedule the delivery of a local notification at the specified date and time and `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` object is used when you want to schedule the delivery of a local notification after the specified number of seconds elapse.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger

Comment: Thanks @Catherine, it seems work for now, I will test it until to end of the day :)

Comment: @HalilİbrahimYÜCE You will need to manually check the end time and cancel the notification once it has passed the end time. Not sure why this isn't mentioned in the answer

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yeah I added an if-else condition for check it, it seems work for now :)  But there is an hour for end time, we will see what happening :)

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson You're right, need to check the end time manually and cancel once it has passed. I'll update in the answer.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I set up end time 16:00 but a couple of minutes ago (16:50) I  still recieved a new notification. The if-else condition seems not working, what do you recommend ?